# Python3.7: Threads and making directories

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm attempting to multithread with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, and within my called function I have to create a directory and copy a file to said directory.

```
def fn():
    ...
    Path(new_dir).mkdir(parents=True)
    while not Path(new_dir).is_dir():
        pass
    copy(filename, path.join(new_dir, filename))
```

The directory and file are created (I checked manually that they exist) but the script throws:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
```

I can run this fine with a process pool (multiprocess.Pool), but I'd like to use threading if possible since, in my case, it is much quicker to complete. Is there a way to force the thread to recognize/wait for completion of the newly created file?

Comment: Are you sure it complains about *target*, not the *source* of the copy? Is ``filename`` inside the current working directory of your script?

Comment: Have you verified that the paths in question are what you think they should be?

Comment: @ScottHunter looks like you hit the nail on the head. I needed to use an absolute path for my directory instead of a relative path

Comment: I don't understand why you would poll for `new_dir`. You just created it. And if you do poll, put a modest sleep in there!

Comment: As a suggestion, when posting an error message, include the stack frame so that we can see which line is the culprit.